# How to create custom search Mixin?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `ListView` which utilizes the `q` `GET` parameter for a search box. The problem is that I am not following the **DRY** principle as I have other search boxes which are similar. Therefore I would like to make a custom `SearchMixin` to handle the search queries. My `ListView` previously looked like this:

```
class MemoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Memo
    template_name = 'memos/memos.html'
    context_object_name = 'memos'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        user_casino = self.request.user.casino
        user_emp_type = self.request.user.employee_type
        ordering = self.get_ordering()

        if query:
            object_list = Memo.objects.filter(
                casino=user_casino).filter(
                receiver=user_emp_type).filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)
                | Q(content__icontains=query
                    )
            )
        else:
            object_list = Memo.objects.filter(
                casino=user_casino).filter(
                receiver=user_emp_type
            )
        return object_list
```

I am trying to create the `SearchMixin` as such:

```
class SearchMixin:

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SearchMixin, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query:
            print('yes')
            return queryset.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)
                                   | Q(content__icontains=query))
        print('no')
        return queryset
```

The problem is that the query is not hitting the `SearchMixin` when I add it to the `MemoListView` as such:

```
class MemoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SearchMixin, ListView):

    model = Memo
    template_name = 'memos/memos.html'
    context_object_name = 'memos'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_casino = self.request.user.casino
        user_emp_type = self.request.user.employee_type
        ordering = self.get_ordering()

        object_list = Memo.objects.filter(
            casino=user_casino).filter(
            receiver=user_emp_type)

        return object_list
```

Why doesn't the search get ran through the `SearchMixin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can try like this:

First, update the `SearchMixin` like this:

```
class SearchMixin:
    model = None
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query:
            print('yes')
            return queryset.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)
                                   | Q(content__icontains=query))
        print('no')
        return queryset
```

Then use it in the `MemoListView`:

```
class MemoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SearchMixin, ListView):
    model = Memo
    template_name = 'memos/memos.html'
    context_object_name = 'memos'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MemoListView, self).get_queryset()
        user_casino = self.request.user.casino
        user_emp_type = self.request.user.employee_type
        ordering = self.get_ordering()

        object_list = queryset.filter(
            casino=user_casino).filter(
            receiver=user_emp_type)

        return object_list
```

Comment: Let's say I have another Mixin I would like to add which uses the `get_queryset` method as well (making 3 `get_queryset` overrides).. Is this the way to handle it?

Comment: yep, make sure that `SearchMixin` is in left most position when using other mixins. For example: `MemoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SearchMixin, AnotherMixin, ListView):`

Answer (score 2):

This will not call the get_queryset of search mixin as it gets override by get_queryset function of the view. You can change the name of get_queryset function in the mixin and then call that function in view using self.